# if polynomials are closer than $\epsilon$, than their deriatives are closer than $C\cdot \epsilon$ for some $C>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose, $P, Q$ are polynomials and $\deg(P) = \deg(Q)$. Furthermore $\|P-Q\| < \epsilon$. Is it true, that $\|P'-Q'\|<C\cdot\epsilon$ for some $C>0$?

Comment: What norm is it?

Comment: $||f|| = \sup|f(x)|$ and, $P,Q\in C^{\infty}([0,1])$.

Comment: Then, if you allow the constant to depend on the degree, [Markov brothers' inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_brothers%27_inequality) seems to do the trick.

Comment: Is $C$ allowed to depend on the degree? For $\max \{\deg P, \deg Q\} \leqslant d$, there is a constant $C_d$, but there is no constant that works for all degrees.

Comment: For fixed degree: derivative is a linear operator on a finite-dimensional normed space, and therefore automatically bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you allow the constant $C$ to depend on the degree $n=\deg P=\deg Q$ (or even $n=\max(\deg P, \deg Q)$), then the result holds by [Markov brothers' inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_brothers%27_inequality) (and generalizes to higher derivatives).

**Note:** this hinges upon the fact that you consider the supremum norm on a compact interval -- and is no longer true if you want to look at the supremum norm on $\mathbb{R}$, for instance.

Now, if you want $C$ to be an absolute constant independent of the degree $n$, then the statement is false. Again, it suffices to look at the same inequality, whose constant $C(n)$ is a growing function of $n$  *and is tight for the [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials).*